# Java Apache CLI Optional Command Line Arguments not working

Tags: java, command-line-interface, apache-commons-cli

Trying to use `Apache Commons Command Line Interface 1.3.1` [from here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/javadocs/api-release/index.html)  It works fine for required arguments, but seems to drop any optional arguments.   Can anyone spot a problem with my code below?

```
import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLine;
import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLineParser;
import org.apache.commons.cli.DefaultParser;
import org.apache.commons.cli.Option;
import org.apache.commons.cli.Options;
import org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException;

public class TestCommandLine {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // *****  test with command line arguments -R myfirstarg -O mysecondarg  *****
        // *****  the second arg is not being captured                          *****

        System.out.println("Number of Arguments : " + args.length);

        String commandline = "";
        for (String arg : args) {
            commandline = commandline + (arg + " ");
        }
        commandline.trim();
        System.out.println("Command-line arguments: " + commandline);

        // create Options object
        Options options = new Options();
        options.addOption("R", true, "Enter this required argument");
        Option optionalargument = Option.builder("O")
                .optionalArg(true)   // if I change this line to .hasArg(true) it works, but then is not optional
                .desc("Enter this argument if you want to")
                .build();
        options.addOption(optionalargument);

        // initialize variables used with command line arguments
        String firstargument = null;
        String secondargument = null;


        CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
        try {
            // parse the command line arguments
            CommandLine cmd = parser.parse( options, args );

            firstargument = cmd.getOptionValue("R");
            secondargument = cmd.getOptionValue("O");

            if(cmd.hasOption("R")){
                if(firstargument == null){
                    System.out.println("Must provide the first argument  ...  exiting...");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("First argument is " + firstargument);
                }
            }
            if(cmd.hasOption("O")) {
                // optional argument
                if (secondargument == null){
                    System.out.println("Second argument is NULL");
                }
                else{
                    // should end up here if optional argument is provided, but it doesn't happen
                    System.out.println("Second argument is " + secondargument);
                }
            }

        }
        catch( ParseException exp ) {
            // oops, something went wrong
            System.err.println( "Parsing failed.  Reason: " + exp.getMessage() );
        }
    }

}
```

The output from the above code is:

```
Number of Arguments : 4
Command-line arguments: -R myfirstarg -O mysecondarg 
First argument is myfirstarg
Second argument is NULL
```

Why isn't "mysecondarg" being captured?
If I change the line .optionalArg(true) to .hasArg(true), then the second argument is captured, but the whole idea is to be able to optionally leave the second argument out.

Comment: What if you set the number of args for it too?

Comment: @ohshazbot:  not sure I follow the question, but if I specify that an argument must be provided for the -O option, then the code works  -- as long as user provides an argument.  But in the actual application, the user needs to be able to select -O and then optionally either provide an argument or not.

Comment: There is an additional flag on the builder for not setting if there are/aren't args, but for setting number of args. It is numberOfArgs

Comment: @ohshzabot:  I don't think that helps, because the number of arguments is variable.  I actually have about 20 different possible command line flags,  some are required and have required arguments while some are optional and have either required arguments or optional arguments.

Comment: @ohshzabot:  I spoke too soon:  I added a line ".numberOfArgs(1)", and that made it work!  Thanks for your help.   Not sure if that is how it is supposed to work, i.e. if it was intended that "numberOfArgs" had to be specified, but it seems to be.   If you respond with an answer I can mark it accepted.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you need to set numberOfArgs in addition to hasOptionalArgs in order for it to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

There is another parse() method that takes a third param option called stopAtNonOption.

Setting stopAtNonOption to false will cause the parsing to fail and throw and exception when an unknown parameter is reached.

I have found out that the parser stops parsing when it reaches an unknown param.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Command-CLI is too verbose, causing misunderstandings and problems. You can use a convenient wrapper for it:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.bogdanovmn.cmdline</groupId>
    <artifactId>cmdline-app</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The original code will look like this (works as you expected):

```java
import com.github.bogdanovmn.cmdline.CmdLineAppBuilder;

public class TestCommandLine {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new CmdLineAppBuilder(args)
            .withArg("R", "Enter this required argument").required()
            .withArg("O", "Enter this argument if you want to")
            .withEntryPoint(options -> {
                // The R arg is required, we shouldn't check it is specified
                System.out.println("First argument is " + options.get("R"));
                if (options.has("O")) {
                    String secondargument = options.get("O");
                    if (secondargument == null) {
                        // Will never go here
                        System.out.println("Second argument is NULL");
                    } else{
                        // should end up here if optional argument is provided
                        System.out.println("Second argument is " + secondargument);
                    }
                }
            })
        .build().run();
    }
}
```

It will throw a runtime exception in case of "-R myfirstarg -O" arguments command line:

```bash
java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing argument for option: O
```

[See documentation for more details](https://github.com/bogdanovmn/java-cmdline-app/blob/master/README.md)